# What is the command for Zipf (frequency against rank) plot in R

Tags: r, rank, network-traffic, frequency-distribution

I have from a network traffic data, data volume (# of bytes) and # of flows over a week period for origin and destination IP pair. I want to plot distribution, i.e. frequency against rank. 
I believe that there is a function already provided by R for that. What is it and how to use that function for my scenario.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out that Zipf plot is just the log-log plot of the frequency of an entity (say 'flows') sorted in descending order.

Comment: log-log plot of rank and frequency

Comment: I downvoted because you posted a question asking for code and then claimed credit for an answer without actually posting any code.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [zipfR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zipfR/index.html) package, and its [dedicated website](http://zipfR.R-Forge.R-project.org/) including the following tutorial: [The zipfR package for lexical statistics: A tutorial introduction](http://zipfR.R-Forge.R-project.org/materials/zipfr-tutorial.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

It hardly seems like you need a special function:

```
x <- rpois(1000, 10)
tbl <- table(x)
plot(seq_along(tbl), unclass(tbl))
```

Or are you looking for `hist`?

```
hist(x)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate this! as I have a file with columns IP pair, number of bytes and number of flows. For this I need to plot origin-destination IP pair by both by data volume and by # of flows (Zipf-type plot)

Answer (score 2):

This should properly be a comment to hadley's answer, but the original question is looking for:

```
plot(log10(seq_along(tbl)), log10(unclass(tbl)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people use the term Zipf plot to mean the log-log plot of the survival function (the inverse of the cumulative probability density). I usually plot it this way:

```
plot(
  log10(rev(sort(data))),
  log10(seq_along(data)/length(data))
)
```